# Can I make this if else statement more efficient

Tags: performance, matlab, if-statement

Anyone on ideas on a more efficient solution than the if else function below?? This takes the bulk of the time for the code so I need to reduce it.

The full function is

```
     function result = vre(t,r,e,n,d)
         if (e==4 && r>0)
        result = 0;
    elseif (e==4 && r==0)
        result = 1;
    elseif (e<4 && r==1)
        result = t;
    elseif (e<4 && r==2)
        result = d;            
    else
        result=n;
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered switch statements?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/functions-used-with-objects.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this function is taking most of your processing time, it is almost certainly because you're calling it too many times.  In turn, this is likely because you are calling it on each element of a vector or matrix individually.  I suggest changing the function to accept matrix inputs for `e` and `r`, so you can perform all the checks at once - `matlab` is built for matrix operations, so taking advantage of those is always a good idea.

```
function result = vre(t,r,e,n,d)
#% add error checking for size of input args if desired
result = ones(size(e))*n; #% default result; next assign special cases
result(e==4 & r>0) = 0; #% note the single & for element-wise 'and'
result(e==4 & r==0) = 1;
result(e<4 & r==1) = t;
result(e<4 & r==2) = d;

end
```

The function now returns a matrix that is the same size as the input matrices - for single elements it will work exactly the same as your current version, but for higher dimensional inputs it will work too, and probably give you a substantial speed boost.

Comment: Guess I spoke too early, running into an error, that the matrix dimensions must agree. I took out the loop and made "r" and "e" column vectors. While "t","n" and "d" are scalars. Any idea why the error

Comment: @Mia what are the sizes of the `r` and `e` vectors? Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: @Mia how significant was the speed-up from doing this?

Comment: Size of r is approx 10^7. To be honest, the speed gain is not significant, it takes 920s for the operation (called 20 times) compared to 1600s before. The main problem is that this is only a fitness function for a genetic approximation so I need compute the fitness function at least 100(seeds)*(20)mutations times, which is 2e6s. Making the problem unfeasible still

Comment: Restarted and the soln time is down now, takes less than 1 minute. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
function result = vre(t,r,e,n,d)
     if (e==4) {
         if(r>0)
             result = 0;
         elseif (r==0)
             result = 1;
     }
     elseif (e<4) {
          if(r==1)
              result = t;
          elseif (r==2)
              result = d; 
     }           
    else
        result=n;
    end
end
```

By doing it this way you'll only verify (e==4) and (e<4) once, avoiding unnecessary verifications.

Hope it saves some processing time.

PS: Not tested since I don't have MatLab installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function result = vre(t,r,e,n,d)
  if (e==4)
    result = (r==0);
  elseif (e<4)
    result = (r==1)*t+(r==2)*d;
  else
    result=n;
  end
end
```

I can't guarantee that it's more efficient (I use octave rather than matlab, so speed testing isn't going to help). But I think it will be.